# ¿Porque '++' no funciona al incrementar un numero dentro del método setState() de React?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial donde tengo el siguiente método de clase:

```
incrementarScore() {
    this.setState({
        score: this.state.score += 1
    });
}
```

El código de arriba funciona perfecto.

Si cambio la línea dentro del método setState() por esta:

```
score: this.state.score += 1
```

también funciona

pero si la cambio por ésta:

```
score: this.state.score ++
```

ya deja de funcionar, lo que me parece más que extraño.

¿ Alguien me podría explicar porque ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te estás confundiendo con lo que hace el operador `++`:

- `++ variable`

Primero incrementa el valor actual. Luego, devuelve ese valor (ya incrementado).

- `variable ++`

Primero **obtiene el valor actual**; después, lo incrementa.

Este último punto es tu caso. Podría decirse que la forma `variable ++` **copia** el valor actual. El valor original, efectivamente, se incrementa ... pero a ti te devuelve **el valor previo** al incremento.

En tu caso, tu código en realidad se ejecuta así:

```
score: this.state.score
this.state.score += 1
```

Puedes resolverlo usando *la otra* forma:

```
score: ++ this.state.score
```

Comment: jaja, respondí 2 segundos después :P

Comment: En mi pueblo se dice *chispita* cuando pasa esto jejeje ... si el OP escoge la tuya, borro esta. Total, decimos lo mismo :-)

Comment: muy buena explicación, gracias a los dos :D

Answer (score 4):

Es porque el operador de incremento puedes usarlo como prefijo o postfijo. Dependiendo de cómo lo uses, te retornará antes o después el nuevo valor.

```
a = 1
a++ // 1
a // 2
++a // 3
a // 3
```